# How to overwrite the UserChangeForm

Tags: python, regex, django, django-forms

Thie is the source code in Django, when change the permission for a user named "xxx///\", it will have an error, but in fact i don't want to block this format username, so i want to overwrite the UserChangeForm class. Could you please tell me how to do this? Thanks!

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.RegexField(
        label=_("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r"^[\w.@+-]+$",
        help_text = _("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                      "@/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages = {
            'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                         "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label=_("Password"),
        help_text=_("Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see "
                    "this user's password, but you can change the password "
                    "using <a href=\"password/\">this form</a>."))

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        f = self.fields.get('user_permissions', None)
        if f is not None:
            f.queryset = f.queryset.select_related('content_type')
```

I finally find the method,add this in the Admin.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
# overwrite the UserChangeForm
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.RegexField(
        label=_("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r"^[a-zA-Z0-9@\.+-_\/\\]+$",
        help_text = _("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                      "@/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages = {
            'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                         ".")})
UserAdmin.form = UserChangeForm
```

Thanks all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex isn't doing what you want. Find some tutorials on regex (google 'Regex Tutorial'). Then I'd suggest getting some software to test regex ([Regex Coach](http://download.cnet.com/The-Regex-Coach/3000-2056_4-10795049.html) on windows is great).

I think the expression `^[a-zA-Z0-9@\.+-_\/\\]+$`. Should do what you're looking for. You'll need to change your help and error text too - you're actually accepting additional characters to the ones you say you're accepting. Lastly, add a `max_length` field to match your existing help text.

```
class CustomChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.RegexField(
        label=_("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r"^[a-zA-Z0-9@\.+-_\/\\]+$",
        help_text = _("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                      "@.+-_/\ only."),
        error_messages = {
            'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                         "@.+-_/\ characters.")}),
        max_length=30)
        ....
```

EDIT

To override the UserChangeForm rewrite the class statement so your form inherits from UserChangeForm instead of ModelForm -

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

class CustomChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    username = forms.RexField(
        ...
```

Have a look at the docs for more information on [inheritance with Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#form-inheritance).

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes, the regex is broken, because the code i pasted is the source code of Django, not myself. I can modify the regex in the code of Django, but i want to overwrite it in my own xx.py file.